# Azure B2C Adding Delete Account

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a working Azure B2C implementation using User Flows. We are using it in an App that runs on Android, and the Google Play Store is now requiring the ability in the app for users to delete their accounts.

There isn't a User Flow for account deletion. I see there is a sample in the custom policies samples https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/delete-my-account . This requires deployment of the custom policy starter kit.

Can anyone tell me if deployment of the custom policy starter kit, and the implementation of the custom account deletion policy, is going to cause a disruption in our current user flows and require reworking of those forms?

Will our current login and logout forms stop working when we upload the custom policy starter kit? And therefore disrupt usage of the App?

We tried uploading just the one custom policy, but it is dependent on a whole chain of base and extention policies, most of which seem entirely unrelated to the issue of account deletion...

Answer (score 0):

The custom flows replace the user flows.

You can't really mix and match them e.g. you can't sign up with a user flow and then sign in with a custom flow.

Yes, there are a series of custom flows that inherit from each other. You have to upload the whole series.

Comment: Will our current login and logout forms stop working when we upload the custom policy starter kit? And therefore disrupt usage of the App?

Comment: No - they can co-exist quite happily.